# php fopen error (failed to open stream: Permission denied)

Tags: php, iis, permissions, git

I have a php script on a Windows Server 2008 box (IIS 7) that is run periodically to download a remote XML file and store it on the server.  This script (which previously used to run successfully), is now failing with the following error:

`Warning: fopen(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\alan\html\xml) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\alan\html\helpers\weather_proxy.php on line 22`

If it matters at all, the only change that I have made was to switch this directory (everything under `alan`) to be a checked out copy of a Git repository.

I have tried or checked the that:

- Directory/file permissions--I've gone so far as to give full control to Everyone, starting at c:\inetpub\wwwroot\alan`, and working all the way down to the file itself in case permissions were not being inherited properly.  For what it's worth, this includes the script itself, as well.
- Safe mode is disabled.

Am I missing something?  The reason that I mentioned the Git checkout is that if I open a Git shell in this directory, it reports `-rw-r--r--` as the effective permissions for the file to which I am attempting to write.  `chmod`ing this file does nothing, according to the bash `ls` readout, but the permissions according to the Windows File Properties dialog report that Everyone has Full Control permissions.  Am I missing something obvious?

**EDIT:** I should point out that this error occurs both when running the script interactively at the command line, as well as through the web server.

Answer (score 1):

Doh! It would make sense to try and write to the file (`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\alan\html\xml\outfile.xml`) instead of the directory (`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\alan\html\xml`), wouldn't it?

Comment: Possible if you could write down the codes in line 22?